# Website that starts at bottom

Tags: website-design

Are there any implications of making a site that starts at the bottom so then you have to scroll up to see everything instead of down?

A bit of context is that the background is fixed and it's post based like a blog so the content is somewhat modular (not like an article but you'd still be reading each post from top to bottom)

Comment: It's great that you are thinking of trying something different (or did you see this somewhere?), and I think that sometimes it takes something a little bit interesting to break the design rules and delight the users.

Comment: Yup, I was just curious for a design I started drafting. I had the title at the bottom and you'd scroll down but instead of scrolling the page down, you'd actually be scrolling the posts down as if you were scrolling the page up.

Comment: Is this a site for proctologists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There would be a fundamental and extremely well established principle of content consumption that would be violated. Not just the web, but for centuries written content has always been written from the top of the page. Sometimes left to right, sometimes right to left and sometimes vertically, but always starting at the top.

Such a website would be incosistent with virtually all other web pages produced and as such would be akin to swapping brake and accelerate pedals although perhaps not with as devastating results.

The f-shaped eye tracking pattern supports this:

http://www.nngroup.com/articles/f-shaped-pattern-reading-web-content/

http://nichcy.org/dissemination/tools/webwriting/reading

I would not advise it. I think your analytics would show a high bounce rate and any observed users would often show confusion because they wouldn't think to scroll up.